Add an asterisk left of an enumerate code review to expl3
In @egreg solution to Compilation problems with custom enumeration, he provides the following definitions:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,color}

\setlist[enumerate]{before=\setupmodenumerate}

\newif\ifmoditem
\newif\ifcitem
\newcommand{\setupmodenumerate}{%
  \global\moditemfalse
  \global\citemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\moditem##1{\global\moditemtrue\def\mesymbol{##1}\item}%
  \def\citem##1{\global\citemtrue\def\cecolor{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{\ifmoditem\llap{\mesymbol\enspace}\else\ifcitem\color{\cecolor}\fi\fi##1}%
    \global\moditemfalse\global\citemfalse}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\moditem{*} test
\citem{blue} test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

I have recently tested this and works fine. Is there a way to make this using expl3 syntax?

did you try and it not work? what went wrong? it would be a lot of work to do it entirely in expl3 because \makelabel, \item etc. are not arbitrary. but you could do most of the rest, though if you use expl3 for colour, it may have unwanted side-effects and/or conflict with other code you're using e.g. packages.

texdoc  latex-lab  to see lists defined using templates, it is a hybrid LaTeX2e + some expl3.

Well, the answer is YES you can, but not without taking several considerations along the way, for example, if you are creating tagged PDF, the \item command is redefined using xparse/ltcmd, so the code you show above will not work correctly, but if what you are looking for is the same effect, you can check the documentation of the new enumext package that has some this function incorporated.

@PabloGonzálezL your package seems interesting. I will review it as I have the following tasks to complete a project: add a label to an item on the left like the objective and level say "8.5a, KSC", highlight the answers in red, show and hide the answers, collect all answers and objectives along with said objectives in a table.

@PabloGonzálezL see my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/730032/10898

@azetina Done :D
