Hiding item label in enumext package
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumext}

\newlength{\ratingwd}
\settowidth{\ratingwd}{\bfseries\footnotesize 8.5a, KSC }
\NewDocumentCommand \rating { }{8.5a, KSC}
\NewDocumentCommand \mywrapp { m }
  {
    \textcolor{red}{\bfseries\footnotesize\rating} \textbf{#1}
  }
\setenumext[enumext, 1]{%
    label={\arabic*},
    font={\bfseries}
%    labelwidth=2.15cm,
    }
\setenumext[enumext, 2]{
    label={\Alph*}, 
    font={\bfseries}
    }
\setenumext[keyans]{
    label={\Alph*}, 
    font={\bfseries}
    }
\begin{document}
\RenewDocumentCommand \mywrapp { m }
  {
   \textbf{#1}
  }
\noindent
Sample Text
\begin{enumext}[
                %list-offset={-\ratingwd},
                %wrap-label={\mywrapp{#1}}, 
                save-ans=test2024,
                show-ans=true,
                wrap-opt={},
                save-sep={~}]
  \item sample         
    \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item*[(8.5a, KSC)] answer
      \item sample
      \item sample
    \end{keyans}
  % Renew \rating here
  \RenewDocumentCommand \rating { }{9.5a, KSC}
  \item sample
      \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item sample
      \item sample
      \item*[(9.5a, KSC)] answer
    \end{keyans}
  \RenewDocumentCommand \rating { }{3.5a, KSC}
  \item sample
      \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item*[(3.5a, KSC)] sample
      \item sample
      \item answer
    \end{keyans}
\end{enumext}

\printkeyans{test2024}
\end{document}

In my previous question Formatting keyvalues in enumext package, the label description per question was correctly added and can be renewed per question. Is it possible to hide them using a better approach? In my attempt above I edit
\setenumext[enumext, 1]{%
    label={\arabic*},
    labelwidth=2.15cm,
    }

to
\setenumext[enumext, 1]{%
    label={\arabic*},
    font={\bfseries}
%    labelwidth=2.15cm,
    }

I also introduced
\RenewDocumentCommand \mywrapp { m }
  {
   \textbf{#1}
  }

and commented
list-offset={-\ratingwd},
wrap-label={\mywrapp{#1}}, 

But am not sure if this is the best approach.

I'm not sure what you want, that 8.5a, KSC 1 sample should only show up as 1 sample?

If that is the case, just put modify the behavior of \mywrapp by means of a boolean, remember that this command is outside the enumext interface so you must manage it from outside.

If I understand correctly, what you want is to manipulate part of label, I propose this:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumext}
\newlength{\ratingwd}
\settowidth{\ratingwd}{\bfseries\footnotesize 11.5a, KSC } % max
\NewDocumentCommand \rating { }{8.5a, KSC}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_azetina_rating_bool
\NewDocumentCommand \showrating { m }
  {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        { true  } { \bool_set_true:N \l_azetina_rating_bool }
        { false } { \bool_set_false:N \l_azetina_rating_bool }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \mywrapp { m }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_azetina_rating_bool
      {
        \makebox[\ratingwd][l]{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries\footnotesize\rating}} ~ \textbf{#1}
      }
      {
        \makebox[\ratingwd][l]{} ~ \textbf{#1} % 
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setenumext[enumext, 1]{%
    label={\arabic*},
    labelwidth=2.15cm,
    }
\setenumext[enumext, 2]{
    label={\Alph*},
    font={\bfseries}
    }
\setenumext[keyans]{
    label={\Alph*},
    font={\bfseries},
    }
\begin{document}

\showrating{true}
\begin{enumext}[list-offset={-\ratingwd},wrap-label={\mywrapp{#1}}, save-ans=test2024,show-ans=true,wrap-opt={},save-sep={ }]
  \item sample
    \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item*[(8.5a, KSC)] answer
      \item sample
      \item sample
    \end{keyans}
  % Renew \rating here
  \RenewDocumentCommand \rating { }{9.5a, KSC}
  \item sample
      \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item sample
      \item sample
      \item*[(9.5a, KSC)] answer
    \end{keyans}
\end{enumext}

\showrating{false}
\RenewDocumentCommand \rating { }{10.5a, KSC}
\begin{enumext}[resume*,save-ans=test2024]% ,show-ans=true,wrap-opt={},save-sep={ }
  \item sample
    \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item*[(10.5a, KSC)] answer
      \item sample
      \item sample
    \end{keyans}
  % Renew \rating here
  \RenewDocumentCommand \rating { }{11.5a, KSC}
  \item sample
      \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item sample
      \item sample
      \item*[(11.5a, KSC)] answer
    \end{keyans}
\end{enumext}

\printkeyans{test2024}
\end{document}



Thanks seems right. I want to be able to show and hide the labels as needed. I will review your code further. I appreciate your patience and understanding.

I will be working on my template and see if I can adapt my settings with your key values in your package and get back if I have more questions.

@azetina I hope this package suits your needs :D.

More than like my next question will be related to the answer symbol if instead of an asterisk it could be like a check mark. But I will try to figure it out. Thanks a lot.
